# Android Product Flavors Manifests

Tags: android

I'm working on my first android app, and I'm just getting started with product flavors.  I have a free version in beta, and I'm starting to make a a paid version.  I'm a bit confused about the manifests.

The paid version will have one activity that the free version does not, and the two will have different permissions.  I'm thinking that I will remove the permissions from the main manifest, that the free manifest will have nothing in it but its permissions, and the paid manifest will have nothing in it but its permissions and the extra activity.

For example, the free manifest might be

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.app">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    </uses-permission>

</manifest>
```

Is this correct?

Comment: Any permissions in common could go in the `main` manifest, just as any components in common can go in the `main` manifest. Otherwise, what you describe sounds fine.

Comment: @CommonsWare Thanks.  Actually, they have no permissions in common; I should have said so.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's correct, however, I would recommend you put all common Manifest information in the `main`, as CommonsWare mentioned.

Also, as a tip, if you do need to replace a value in the `main` Manifest for any reason (debugging for example), I would use the `tools:replace` tag like so:

Free flavor:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
      package="com.example">

    <application
        android:name=".FreeApp"
        android:allowBackup="false"
        tools:replace="allowBackup,name"/>

</manifest>
```

This would replace the tags `name` and `allowBackup` from `main` with what you have in this manifest.

I recommend you check out the following link for more information about flavoring and variants, in case you haven't already:

https://developer.android.com/studio/build/build-variants.html

Comment: Thanks for the tip.  I deduce from your example that when I add the new activity in the  paid app, I should include `android:name=".PaidApp"` or whatever suffix I used in the build.gradle file.  Am I right?

Comment: The `android:name` tag follows the folder structure of your project, regardless of what your build.gradle file says. If you are trying to understand manifest merging and which manifest takes priority during the process, here is another helpful link to help you understand it: https://developer.android.com/studio/build/manifest-merge.html

Comment: To answer you question, if the `main` manifest doesn't have the activity you are adding, but your `paid` manifest does, you shouldn't have any conflict and everything should automatically merge without issues for you.